# Customizing FlexSlider 2

Tags: html, css, flexslider

I'm using flexslider and it's amazing responsive, working perfect...
But you know the *.flex-control-nav* ? The little balls that allow you to control the slides?
I'd like to position it, right beside the slide. 
And if possible, change the little balls for little balls with numbers inside it.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EAL7b/2/

Is there a way to set this kind of customization ?

I'm confused because all I have in my HTML is this:

Obs: *slideholder* and *container* are custom divs that I've created to centralize the slide.

```
<div id="slideholder">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="flexslider">
         <ul class="slides">
        <li>
           <img src="Imgs/nature-photo.png"class="img-responsive" />
        </li>
        <li>
           <img src="Imgs/nature-photo6.png" class="img-responsive"/>
        </li>
         <li>
        <img src="Imgs/nature-photo3.png" class="img-responsive" />
         </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle or CSS snippet?

Comment: @88MPG Sure, it's on the question.